# Im trying to map a joystick to a servo but need the servo to be at 0 when the joystick is in nerural. And up to 180 when joy is forward or back

Tags: servo, joystick

Im trying to map a joystick to a servo but need the servo to be at 0 when the joystick is in nerural. And up to +180 when joy is forward or back.

I just cant seem to figure out the mapping or setup for the code for this part.
I remember seeing it done before but my google skils are failing me and i cant seem to find it again.
Thanks

Comment: it is a simple arithmetic problem ... convert `-180 0 180` to `180 0 180`

Comment: jsotola. I know it should be something simple. But cant seem to get it working.  Any help on actually doing it would be appreciated

Comment: You could map from -180 to 180 and then take the absolute value of that. I'm sure there is a function for that

Comment: use something like this `if (val < 0)  val = 0 - val;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this one although, the others answered you properly :

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;
int potpin = 1;
int val;

void setup () {
    myservo.attach(9);
}

void loop () {
    val = analogRead(potpin);
    val = map(val, 0, 1023, 0, 360);
    myservo.write(val);
    delay(20);
}
```

Connect the signal wire of your Servomotor to PWM pin number 9 of Arduino
Connect the output of your joystick to A1 pin of your arduino

Actually i'm not sure about one of that lines and i forgot the correct form, if didn't work, change this line :

```
val = map(val, 0, 1023, 0, 360);
```

To this :

```
val = map(val, 0, 1023, -180, 180);
```

I think both of them works

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` function, see [Arduino Map Function](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/).

So in your case, assuming a `value` of 0..1023 coming from an analog pin, where 0 needs to be mapped to -180 and 1023 to +180, you get

```
int mappedValue = map(value, 0, 1023, -180, 180);
```

(note I assume you mean -180 when backwards, +180 when forwards).

**UPDATE**

It seems value 0 (backward) needs to be mapped to 180, 512 (neutral) to 0, and 1023 (forward) to 180 (again).

For this you need two maps depending on the value:

```
int mappedValue = 0;
if (value < 512) // Backwards
{
    mappedValue = map(value, 0, 511, 180, 0);
}
else // Forward
{
    mappedValue = map(value, 512, 1023, 0, 180);
}
```

Comment: Im tyring to get the servo to move + 180 when the joy is forward.   And also +180 when the joy is pulled back. And the servo to sit at 0 when the joy is in netural. The servo im using has a range from 0-180

Comment: and what are the values of the joystick in forward, neutral and backward positions?

Comment: The joystick values are 0 for back. 1023 for forward.   Thank you